# Webpack #.bundle.js files

Tags: webpack

Webpack is creating multiple bundles files, like so:

- 0.bundle.js
- 1.bundle.js
- 2.bundle.js
- bundle.js

It seems that it creates a file for each import, and the last "bundle.js" is for the index.js entry file.
Why cant I get a single output file?

Answer (score 1):

This is called code-splitting and it is the best practice to do on the web today. It process every single `import` clause you have and create a different bundle for it. You cant disable.